# WPF ListView Scrollbars

Tags: wpf

Ok, I give up - how do I get the vertical scroll bars to appear on a list view without specifing a hard coded value for the MaxHeight in the xaml?

here is my xaml (i've not included the data model, but it's basically a directory listing)

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.FolderViewView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500" >
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Label Name="lblFolder" Content="{Binding Path=FolderName}" MinWidth="250"/>
        <Button Name="btnFolder" Content="Select Folder" Click="btnFolder_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DockPanel>
        <ListView Name="lstFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="1" MaxHeight="200" Height="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Filename" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Extenstion" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Extension}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileSize}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Creation Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CreateDate}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Modified Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ModifiedDate}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Without setting MaxHeight on the ListView control, the scroll bar does not appear when there are enough items to make the List view larger than the screen.
With MaxHeigt="250", the scroll bar appears, but now the list view doesn't extend when the user changes the size of the window.

Maybe I'm asking the wrong question and it should be: How do I change the max height of the listview when the height of the window is changed?

Please help, this has been driving me up the wall for the last day now...

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem comes from the usage of `DockPanel`. By default it gives its child all the space it requires (regardless available space).

In order to fix it I suggest you use the `Grid` panel instead of `DockPanel`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Name="lblFolder" Content="{Binding Path=FolderName}" MinWidth="250"/>
        <Button Name="btnFolder" Content="Select Folder" Click="btnFolder_Click" />
    </StackPanel>


    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="lstFiles" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="1" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Filename" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Extenstion" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Extension}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileSize}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Creation Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CreateDate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Modified Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ModifiedDate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry, this still doesn't work for me, the items still drop off the bottom of the page, and the scroll bar doesn't become visible. Even specifically setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" on the ListView.

Comment: @Lee - Then, the problem is with the markup that contains this UserControl. Could add it to your question so I could take a look?

Comment: here is the host window `<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="itemcontrol" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Window>`

Comment: And the code behind that adds the control `        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Presenters.FolderViewPresenter folderpresenter = new Presenters.FolderViewPresenter();
            itemcontrol.Items.Add(folderpresenter.m_View);
        }`

Comment: @Lee - Now I see the problem. You use an ItemsControl to host your UserControl. ItemsControl uses StackPanel to host its children and it gives its children all the space they want regardless available space. One way to fix that is to wrap ItemsControl into a ScrollViewer: <Grid> <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"> <ItemsControl x:Name="itemcontrol" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" /> </ScrollViewer></Grid>

Comment: Great thanks. That's much better, however it does now scroll the whole control, but I can work with that. Is there a better way for me to host the user control, considering I've currently only got one control at a time in the ItemsControl collection?

Comment: use the "UserControl" instead of the "ItemsControl" and set the content to the presenter's view - duh...Thanks for your help

Comment: @Lee - Just use ContentPresenter and set its Content property to an instance of your UserControl: contentPresenter.Content = folderpresenter.m_View; Then you don't need to wrap it in a ScrollViewer.